# Rails RSS Feed Builder per item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Right now I have one RSS feed that gets a list of episodes that belong_to a metro. What I'd like to do is generate an RSS feed **per metro**. So city1.rss, city2.rss, city3.rss, cityN.rss.

**routes.rb**

```
resources :metros do
     collection do
       get :feed
     end
  end
```

**metros_controller.rb**

```
  def feed
    @metros = Metro.all
    @episodes = Episode.published.order("created_at DESC")

    @metros.each do |metro|
        metro.rss { render action: :index, name: @metro.name }
    end
  end
```

**index.rss.builder**

```
xml.rss :version => "2.0", "xmlns:itunes" => "http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd",  "xmlns:media" => "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/", "xmlns:atom" => "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" do
  xml.channel do
    xml.title title
    xml.description description
    xml.language 'en'
    xml.pubDate @episodes.first.created_at.to_s(:rfc822)
    xml.lastBuildDate @episodes.first.created_at.to_s(:rfc822)
    xml.itunes :author, author
    xml.itunes :keywords, keywords
    xml.itunes :explicit, 'clean'
    xml.itunes :image, :href => image_url('cover.jpg')
    xml.itunes :owner do
      xml.itunes :name, author
    end
    xml.itunes :block, 'no'
    xml.itunes :category, :text => 'News' do
      xml.itunes :category, :text => 'News'
    end

    @episodes.each do |episode|
      xml.item do
        xml.title episode.title
        xml.description episode.description
        xml.pubDate episode.created_at.to_s(:rfc822)
        xml.enclosure :url => episode.s3, :length => 5, :type => 'mp3'
        xml.link episode_url(episode)
        xml.guid({:isPermaLink => "false"}, episode_path(episode))
        xml.itunes :author, author
        xml.itunes :subtitle, truncate(episode.description, :length => 150)
        xml.itunes :summary, episode.description
        xml.itunes :explicit, 'no'
        xml.itunes :duration, 5
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The error I'm getting is:

> undefined method `rss' for #Metro:0x00007faaaa96b278

Comment: I commented with untested code of a general idea, on what you must do. Not sure if it is completely correct for rails 4 (or rails 5 for that matter)

Comment: I highly recommend, you go throug some tutorial concering routing and handling paramaters and formats, as you missed some key aspects there.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create multiple RSS feeds when the request goes to `metros/feed.rss`

First you need to setup the right`routes`, the most important thing being, that you want to pass a `parameter` to the `action`.

routes.rb

```
resources :metros do
  get ':city' to: 'metros#feed' #creates a named parameter 
end
```

So now if you can theoretically call `metros/chigaco.rss` you can use chicago in your `metros_controller.rb`

```
def feed
  @metro = Metro.find_by_name(params[:name])
  @episodes = @metro.episodes.published.order("created_at DESC")
  render action: :index, name: @metro.name 
end
```

The problem is this won't work, as the route `/metros/:id' that points to index takes precedence. So it is better to set up a seperate route for that:

```
  get 'feed/:name', to: 'metros#feed'
```